# How does Sticky session works?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have this code(Copied from github) which create four(no of cpu cores) child instance of master.I have used sticky session for my socket connection to connect properly to backend and redis adapter message broker.But I cant understand how it is working.
Can someone please explain line line by what is happening

```
    http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    socketIO = require('socket.io'),
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    socket_redis=require('socket.io-redis')


  var app = express(), io;

  server = http.Server(app);
  app.set('view engine','ejs');
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('send message by worker: ' + cluster.worker.id);
    res.render('abhi');
});

  io = socketIO(server);
  io.adapter(socket_redis({host:'localhost',port:'6379'}))
  io.on("connection",s=>{
      s.on("new",data=>{
          console.log("hey you")
      })
  })

  // Add your socket.IO connection logic here


if(!sticky.listen(server,port))
{
  server.once('listening', function() {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
  });

  if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('Master server started on port '+port);
  } 
}
else {
    console.log('- Child server started on port '+port+' case worker id='+cluster.worker.id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to explain sticky session based on your code you provided. But, in a short explanation; I believe socket.io keeps the connected sockets as a thread/object in it's thread. So when you send a packet/request to a socket(.io) server that packet/request has to reach to the process/server that you made your handshake. Or else it'll most likely fail.

If you are looking for a sticky session and clustering I'd advise you to check out [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis), it makes things quite easy and smooth.
And to run your nodejs process many times to utilize your entire cpu, you can either use Docker and summon containers for each thread/cpu depending on your setup(which I did for a while ago and they seemed quite good) or you can use nodejs' cluster library.

Comment: Yes,but the main problem I am facing is how is master forking the child process because there is no loop iterating over the no cpu cores and forking it.I dont seem to understand this part